# Ubuntu 22.04 autoinstall partiotioning with condition

Tags: partitioning, cloud-init

I'm using Ubuntu autoinstall to install my software on Ubuntu 22.04, **during** OS installation, non-interactively (from ISO). 
We have one disk mapped to the server. My software installation requires the following partitioning scheme;
**If** disk size is above 1TB:

```
/tmp - 5%
/ - 10%
/var - 30%
/opt - rest
```

**If** the disk size is 1TB and below, all the disk size should be allocated to /.

Do you have a suggestion on how I should do it?

Answer (score 1):

Solution -

In my example, the **minimum** disk size should be at least 52 GB. Inside autoinstall's `storage` section I'm adding `/boot` as 1GB, and `/` as 50GB (**LVM**).
Then, inside the `user-data` section, I'm running a bash script that increases VG to the maximum available, and creates partitions (`/opt, /var, /tmp`) if the disk is above 1TB, otherwise, it increase `/` to maximum available.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `early-commands` to modify the `/autoinstall.yaml` file.  This autoinstall file shows the basic concept by changing the `/autoinstall.yaml` file depending on the size of `/dev/sda`.  It is not a working example since it does not provide a valid storage config.

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  storage:
    config: []
  early-commands:
    - |
      if [ $(blockdev --getsize64 /dev/sda) -gt 1000000000000 ]; then
        sed -i -e 's/    config: ../    config: complex/' /autoinstall.yaml
      else
        sed -i -e 's/    config: ../    config: simple/' /autoinstall.yaml
      fi
```

As the [autoinstall reference](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall-reference#early-commands) documents

> The autoinstall config is available at /autoinstall.yaml (irrespective
> of how it was provided) and the file will be re-read after the
> early-commands have run to allow them to alter the config if
> necessary.

It will not be trivial to insert something as complex as the storage config but it should be possible.