setting static ip by mac address for 24.04 desktop autoinstall
i'm wondering if there is a recommended method for setting unique static ip addresses, by mac address, when autoinstalling ubuntu desktop 24.04.
we are testing a pxe boot setup with the 24.04.1 desktop .iso downloading over http and the autoinstall user-data yaml file hosted on the http server.
i was hoping that having a network block with multiple match: keys in user-data would allow for unique static addresses to be applied, but with duplicate keys it looks like only the final set gets picked up for the netplan yaml file in the install environment. for example, just the details for xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:ab/10.0.0.3/16 gets picked up from below.
not sure if i am missing something obvious, or if this is the wrong approach. any help is greatly appreciated.
  network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
      enp0s31f6:
        match:
          macaddress: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:aa
        dhcp4: false
        addresses:
          - 10.0.0.2/16
        routes:
          - to: default
            via: 10.0.0.1
        nameservers:
          search:
            - domain.local
          addresses:
            - 10.0.0.1
        match:
          macaddress: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:ab
        dhcp4: false
        addresses:
          - 10.0.0.3/16
        routes:
          - to: default
            via: 10.0.0.1
        nameservers:
          search:
            - domain.local
          addresses:
            - 10.0.0.1


i think i found a lead at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1433362/ubuntu-22-04-autoinstall-partiotioning-with-condition using early-commands to modify the autoinstall.yaml file. testing to see if this also works for 24.04.

not sure if this is the ideal way to handle the situation but this seems to be working:

created mac.sh script to check an array of mac addresses against the mac address of the install environment. it then updates /autoinstall.yaml accordingly with matching mac and ip address (from the second array). note: /autoinstall.yaml is created in the install environment from http://[pxeserver]/user-data.

#!/bin/bash
mac=("xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:aa" "xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:ab")
ip=("10.0.0.2\/16" "10.0.0.3\/16")
for i in "${!mac[@]}"; do
  if [ "$(ip a | grep ether | cut -d ' ' -f6)" == "${mac[i]}" ]; then
    sed -i -e "s/          macaddress: null/          macaddress: ${mac[i]}/" /autoinstall.yaml
    sed -i -e "s/          - ipaddress/          - ${ip[i]}/" /autoinstall.yaml
  fi
done


updated user-data to have early-commands that copy over the script, make it executable, and run it.

  early-commands:
    - wget -O /mac.sh http://[pxeserver]/mac.sh
    - chmod +x /mac.sh
    - /mac.sh
    - sleep 3


Made the network section of user-data generic. note: when this gets copied to /autoinstall.yaml macaddress: is set to macaddress:null.

  network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
      enp0s31f6:
        match:
          macaddress:
        dhcp4: false
        addresses:
          - ipaddress
        routes:
          - to: default
            via: 10.0.0.1
        nameservers:
          search:
            - domain.local
          addresses:
            - 10.0.0.1

